# Script does not wait for statement to finish and starts executing next line

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

I am having a scenario that if an application is already installed, then first uninstall the older version, then install new version.

I have written following piece of code in a batch file using VBScript:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

path="C:\Program Files\MySetup\My App 3.5" 'path to folder    
exists = fso.FolderExists(path)

if (exists) then 
    WshShell.Run "msiexec /qb /x {3D5D4357-217C-49BA-A8E8-00907D631F05}  "  
end if
    WshShell.Run "msiexec /qb /i C:\Build\" & msiFileName
```

I am facing an issue that when execution goes to `if (exist)` block, lets assume application is already installed, then it goes inside `if` block and start uninstall the application and runs it asynchronously and start executing the next line (installing the new version) and it cause a problem that "another installation is already in progress".

All I want that once it goes for uninstalling the application, it should wait until it is finished, then only go to next line for execution (installing newer version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the third parameter of [`WSHShell.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), set it to true to wait for completion of the command.

```
if (exists) then 
    WshShell.Run "msiexec /qb /x {3D5D4357-217C-49BA-A8E8-00907D631F05}  " ,0,true
end if
WshShell.Run "msiexec /qb /i C:\Build\" & msiFileName,0,true
```

Comment: I have used what you have specified but still it not waiting the statement to complete.

Comment: Check if there's anything to uninstall, add a key to log the activity of `msiexec` and analyze, there might probably be uninstallation/MSIexec respective errors.